# How to add response to HelloWorld in Solidity Remix?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I want to add a response to [this Hello World example](https://solidity-by-example.org/hello-world).

###### HelloWorld.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// compiler version must be greater than or equal to 0.8.13 and less than 0.9.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract HelloWorld {
    string public greet = "Hello World!";
    string public respond = "Good morning, starshine!"; // trying to add this line
}
```

When I run the [contract in Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) before the line I'm attempting to add, I see this...

[image]

What I expect to see after my added line is another button called <kbd>respond</kbd> and when I press it, I expect below it to read:

> string: Good morning, starshine!

But instead, I see no change than when run without my added line.

How do I achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no errors in your code
you have to redeploy the contract again by clicking orange Deploy button